# JMeter: Gaussian random timer vs Poisson random timer

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to figure out which timer to use for my loadtests in order to simulate a gradual growth in traffic towards the website.
I had a look ad the Gaussian Random Timer:

> To delay every user request for random amount of time use Gaussian
>   Random Timer with most of the time intervals happening near a specific
>   value.

and the Poisson random timer:

> To pause each and every thread request for random amount of time use
>   Poisson Random Timer with most of the time intervals occurring close a
>   specific value.

taken from [this source.](http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/timers-in-jmeter-tutorial-series-6/)

Now I don't really understand what's the difference between the two. They both apply a random delay that is more likely to be close to a specific value. So what am I missing? How to they differ in practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the algorithm used to generate random values:

Poisson is based on this:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution
- http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/14/generating-poisson-random-values/

Gaussian uses :

- [java.util.Random#nextGaussian()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29)

Both add to Constant Delay Offset the value of a random number generated based on either Poisson or Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in underlying algorythm, check the following links for details

- [Normal (Gaussian) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)
- [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

I would also recommend reading [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for exhaustive information on JMeter timers.